# Use Arara directives to move pdf from build folder to root folder

Tags: arara

I am trying to have all auxilliary files created in a "_build" subdirectory, but automatically move the created PDF back to the same directory as the .tex.

In other words, I want the .tex and .pdf in one folder, and the other build files in a "_build" folder.

I think I can achieve this with arara's move command. But I can't work out how to automate the filename.

MWE:

```
% arara: lualatex: { options:  [ '--output-directory=_build' ], draft: true }
% arara: biber: { options: ['--output_directory=_build'] }
% arara: lualatex: { options:  [ '--output-directory=_build' ], synctex: true }
% arara: lualatex: { options:  [ '--output-directory=_build' ], synctex: true }
% arara: move: {  files: [ '_build/tmp.pdf' ], target: ['./'] }

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

I'd rather not need to change the preamble for every new document or filename change. But I can't work out how to get something like this to work:

```
% arara: move: {  files: [ '_build/@{getBasename(currentFile())}.pdf' ], target: ['./'] }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an error in two steps: First of all, in `files` there is no orb-tag expansion so your `getBasename` call won't work. Second, with fixed file name it works for me (on Linux), so you probably omit some relevant details.

Comment: The MWE above does work. The problem is that I want this to be a template I can use many times and it will have a different filename each time. Rather than needing to change the filename each time, I was hoping to automate finding it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, orb tag expansion is allowed only within `options` and no other key, so the attempt of expanding the base name reference inside `files` will fail. This is by design, as the team don't want arbitrary orb tag expansion. That said, feature requests are always welcome. `:)`

The typical way to tackle this scenario would be with a custom rule, perhaps with an extension of the existing `move` one. However, in this answer, I will take another route and provide a solution within the conditional scope using MVEL and Java methods:

```
% arara: lualatex: { options:  [ '--output-directory=_build' ] }
% arara: halt if a = getOriginalReference().getName();
% arara: --> b = a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf('.'));
% arara: --> c = toFile(b + '.pdf');
% arara: --> d = toFile('_build/' + b + '.pdf');
% arara: --> d.renameTo(c); true

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Let us break down what's happening here, from the second line on:

```
% arara: halt if a = getOriginalReference().getName();
```

I will use the `halt` directive for this case, as it simply halts the tool. The first part of the conditional gets the original reference (regardless of `files`) and extract the file name, as a string. The variable `a` then holds  just the `.tex` file name (without path reference).

```
% arara: --> b = a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Variable `b` holds the file name from `a` without its corresponding extension. This would be equivalent to getting the base name, so e.g., if `a = foo.tex`, then `b = foo`.

```
% arara: --> c = toFile(b + '.pdf');
```

Variable `c` now holds the file base name plus the `.pdf` suffix, as a `File` reference.

```
% arara: --> d = toFile('_build/' + b + '.pdf');
```

Similarly, variable `d` holds the file base name plus the `.pdf` suffix, appended to the `_build/` string, indicating the path location. The variable holds all of this as a `File` reference.

```
% arara: --> d.renameTo(c); true
```

Now, having two `File` references, we simply tell `d` to be renamed to `c` by using the `renameTo(...)` method from Java. Finally, I simply end the conditional with `true`, which indicates that `halt` should proceed.

Hope it helps. `:)`

*Update from comments:* when using `renameTo(...)`, one might observe that the behaviour of this method is [inherently platform-dependent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29). A possible alternative to this is exploiting the `move` operation from NIO `Files` with `StandardCopyOption`. Replace the last directive line

```
% arara: --> d.renameTo(c); true
```

by

```
% arara: --> java.nio.file.Files.move(d.toPath(), c.toPath(),
% arara: --> java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
% arara: --> true
```

and that should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer! I have only one issue with the solution: if the .pdf already exists in the base directory, this silently fails.

How would I tell the renameTo() method from Java to overwrite an existing file?

Comment: I have also added a `c.delete()` step to remove the .pdf if it already exists, though there might be a better way to handle overwriting the file?

Comment: @jw5801 I wrote an addendum, hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: ERROR MSG: `For whatever reason, I could not compile the expression in the
provided conditional. This part is quite tricky, since it
involves aspects of the underlying expression language. I will do
my best to help you in any way I can. There are more details
available on this exception:

DETAILS ---------------------------------------------------------
[Error: unable to resolve method:
org.islandoftex.arara.api.files.MPPPath.getName()
[arglength=0]]
[Near : {... @{ a = getOriginalReference().
....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]`